# double colon in url is loading indefinitely in a Webview and is treated as valid URL

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a android webview and when I load a url with double colon after http it is loading indefinitely.

url used

> http:://example.com/

all my methods in WebViewClient is also not being called

- shouldOverrideUrlLoading
- onPageStarted
- onPageFinished
- onReceivedError

so I cannot determine if an error is encountered when loading.

I tried to check it the url is valid via this code but it is still treated as a valid URL

```
    public static boolean isValidUrl(String urlString) {
        boolean result = true;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            url.toURI();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Is this expected in android webview?

Comment: why r u using double :: in your url - http:://example.com/

Comment: its for error testing; I want to handle it as error but the webview is loading non-stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the below code:**

```
private boolean isURLCanBeLoadedToWebview(String urlString) {
   return Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(urlString).matches();
}
```

Comment: URLUtil.isValidUrl and Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher does not accept URL as parameters, but you lead me to the right direction;

Comment: What I think I need is `Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches();` since i want for all URL to be properly loaded in Android webview; `URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)` returns `false` for url "www.example.com" even though it can be still loaded in the webview

Comment: I edited your answer to suit my needs; I will accept it as answer when you approved it

Comment: use try catch to avoid any app crash pls in your code